# Provide a variable name as a string using rlang in if_else and df$

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

In the following code,

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% mutate(var2 = if_else(mpg >20, 1, 0))
as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$mpg))
```

I want to parametrize mpg as

```
var1 <- "mpg"
```

but, the following code is not throwing the correct results, am sure I am not using the rlang correctly.

```
mtcars %>% mutate(var2 = if_else(!!quo(var1) >20, 1, 0))
as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$!!quo(var1)))
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the string to symbol and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(var2 = if_else(!! rlang::sym(var1) >20, 1, 0))
```

The `ifelse` is not needed here as `as.integer` can coerce the TRUE/FALSE to `1/0`

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(var2 =  as.integer(!! rlang::sym(var1) >20))
```

---

For the second piece of code, we can use `[[` instead of `$` to extract the column

```
as.numeric(mtcars[[var1]])
```

---

If there is some doubt about the expression with quosures, use `qq_show` to understand the underlying issue

```
rlang::qq_show(mtcars %>% 
          mutate(var2 = if_else(!!quo(var1) >20, 1, 0)))
#mtcars %>% mutate(var2 = if_else((^var1) > 20, 1, 0))
```

and now with symbol conversion

```
rlang::qq_show( mtcars %>% 
             mutate(var2 = if_else(!! rlang::sym(var1) >20, 1, 0)))
#mtcars %>% mutate(var2 = if_else(mpg > 20, 1, 0))
```

Note in the first case, it is evaluated as 'var1' and not the column 'mpg'

Comment: Ok, can we do something about as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$!!quo(var1))) then?

Comment: It does for the first line, Thank you! There is one more line in my code if you know how to fix that as well: as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$!!quo(var1)))

Comment: @Geet  Don't use `$` for that, use `[[` i.e. `as.numeric(mtcars[[var1]])`